# How to get Item Custom options after order success in magento?

Tags: magento

when any customer completed order and redirect on successpage than i want Ordered Item selected Custom Option and insert into separate table in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code for get Item selected custom options after order completed.

```
$lastRealOrderId = $session->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($lastRealOrderId); 
$opt_label = array();
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $i){
        $prod_opts = $i->getData('product_options');
        $prod_opts = unserialize($prod_opts);

        foreach($prod_opts['options'] as $opt){
           $opt_value = $opt['value'];
        }

        $option_val_first = str_split($opt_value,8);
        $package_month = $option_val_first[0];
    }
```